# Trying to use iconv to convert US-ASCII to UTF-16LE and getting undesired output

Tags: bash, character-encoding, ascii, iconv, utf-16le

I'm trying to convert a file `System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll.refresh` from ASCII to UTF-16LE. When I run the `file -i` command on other refresh files in the directory, I get something like:

`System.Web.Optimization.dll.refresh: text/plain; charset=utf-16le`

And when I run it on my target file I get:

`System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll.refresh: text/plain; charset=us-ascii`

I think this encoding difference is causing an error in my build pipeline, so I'm trying to convert this ASCII file to UTF-16LE so it's like the other refresh files. However, `iconv` doesn't seem to be giving me the output I'm looking for.

My command:

`iconv -f US-ASCII -t UTF-16LE "System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll.refresh" > "System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll.refresh.new" && mv -f "System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll.refresh.new" "System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll.refresh"`

There are two issues with the output.

1) It spaces the file out (i.e. from `this` to `t h i s`).

2) When I run `file -i` on this new file, I get the following output:

`System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll.refresh: application/octet-stream; charset=binary`

Why am I getting this binary output, and why is it spacing out the text? Is there a better way to convert this file to the proper encoding?

Comment: If you're looking at a UTF-16 encoded file in something that expects a one-byte code unit instead of it's 2-byte units, yeah, you're going to get funny results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file` is showing your new file as binary data because it relies on a leading [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to tell if the contents are encoded in UTF-16. When you specify the endianness, `iconv` will leave out the BOM:

```
$ iconv -f us-ascii -t utf16le <<<test | xxd
00000000: 7400 6500 7300 7400 0a00                 t.e.s.t...
```

However, if you let it use the native endianness (Which on typical modern hardware is going to be LE 99% of the time):

```
$ iconv -f us-ascii -t utf16 <<<test | xxd
00000000: fffe 7400 6500 7300 7400 0a00            ..t.e.s.t...
```

the mark is there, and `file -i` will report it as `foo.txt: text/plain; charset=utf-16le`.

I'm not aware of a way to force `iconv` to always add the BOM with an explicit UTF-16 endianness. Instead, here's a `perl` one-liner that will convert to explicit UTF-16LE and add the BOM:

```
perl -0777 -pe 'BEGIN{binmode STDOUT,":encoding(utf16le)"; print "\x{FEFF}"}' in.txt > out.txt
```

Or alternatively using `printf` to print the LE-encoded BOM and `iconv` for the rest:

```
(printf "\xFF\xFE"; iconv -f us-ascii -t utf-16le in.txt) > out.txt
```

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Thank you so much!